# Angular8 ngfor FormControl

Tags: angular

How to bind `mat-option` to `control`? I tried something like `<mat-option *ngFor="let option of control.value" [value]="option">`, `<mat-option *ngFor="let option of control.value['option']" [value]="option">` and another variants. But still not working.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of myForm.controls | keyvalue">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="{{control.key}}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
          {{option.parameter}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  options = [{ type: "first", parameter: "first" }, { type: "first", parameter: "first" }];
  secondOptions = [{ type: "second", parameter: "second " }, { type: "second", parameter: "second" }];
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl(this.options),
    second: new FormControl(this.secondOptions)
  });

  constructor() {
    this.myForm.controls
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you bind your options to a control ? Options are one of many choices for **on control**, you don't need to bind them.

Comment: @Maryannah but i want to make each select should show his own select list. Now first and second select shows only list from options.

Comment: Still, you don't need to bind your options to a form control. Also, form controls usually contain primitive values (string, number, boolean). Providing an array as a value would mean it's something like a checkbox (which isn't) or a select with multiple options selected (which isn't either). Let me make an answer for you.

Comment: You need to put `*ngFor` on parent

Comment: It is better to only store the value inside a formControl, not the options. Keep the options outside of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the options outside of the FormControl, do not set options as the value, you need to handle the options outside of the controls.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of myForm.controls | keyvalue">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="{{control.key}}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options[control.key]" [value]="option">
          {{option.parameter}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

TS. Note that we created an options object, with attribute names that has the same name as our controls

```
options = {
    first:  [
      { type: "first", parameter: "first" }, { type: "first", parameter: "first" }
    ],
    second: [
      { type: "second", parameter: "second " },
      { type: "second", parameter: "second" }
    ]
  }
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl(),
    second: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor() {
    this.myForm.controls
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/options-outside-formcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

Following my comments, you should not bind your options to a form control.

Instead, simply create a two-dimensional array like so :

```
groups = [
  { controlName: 'first', options : [{ type: "first", parameter: "first" }, { type: "first", parameter: "first" }] },
  { controlName: 'second', options : [{ type: "second", parameter: "second " }, { type: "second", parameter: "second" }] },
];

myForm = new FormGroup({
  first: new FormControl(),
  second: new FormControl()
});
```

And iterate over it.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of groups">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="obj.controlName">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of obj.options | keyvalue" [value]="option">
          {{ keyval.parameter }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry but i got error "Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined"